# Agendar job sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma procedure que desejaria que fosse executada a cada X tempo. Fiz o agendamento no sql agent tudo certinho. Minha dúvida é o seguinte, preciso replicar essa procedure em todas as bases para poder utilizar com o comando:
*EXEC sp_MSforeachdb USE ? PROC_REL_VISTA_ACOMPANHAMENTO* ?

Comment: Basta criar procedure no Master e chama-la de qualquer outra base.

Comment: Por gentileza colega poste o código da sua procedure isto facilitará na ajuda para vermos o seu conceito.